# 403 issues with Convertigo on localhost with Chrome 80

Tags: angular, google-chrome, session, cookies, convertigo

Since Chrome 80, I have sessions/cookies issues with Convertigo Angular SDK when I launch a developer server reachable on localhost. Convertigo create many new sessions instead of only one and send 403 errors on fullsync requests

Here is the request headers : [403 errors & response headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSXh5.png)

No problem on other browsers or on deployed urls

Thank you
Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our recommendation now is to disable the **SameSite** protection for your Chrome :

1. open **chrome://flags/**
2. search for **SameSite**
3. disable **SameSite by default cookies**
4. disable **Cookies without SameSite must be secure**

This affect only developers and not applications in production (served by the same domain).

If you want tho know more about **SameSite** : https://web.dev/samesite-cookies-explained/